# Intercept method calls and add / enrich parameters

Tags: java, spring, aop, feign

I'm writing a rest api client that needs to connect to some APIs (same API) on different endpoints, all serving the same data. For that, I need to dynamically set each calls url and auth header. Since I'm using spring as a framework, my plan was to use feign as the rest client.

Below is what I need to do in code

Feign Client:

```
@FeignClient(
    name = "foo",
    url = "http://placeholderThatWillNeverBeUsed.io",
    fallbackFactory = ArticleFeignClient.ArticleClientFallbackFactory.class
)
public interface ArticleFeignClient {
    @GetMapping(value = "articles/{id}", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public ArticleResponse getArticles(URI baseUrl, @RequestHeader("Authorization") String token, @PathVariable Integer id);

    @GetMapping(value = "articles", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public MultiArticleResponse getArticles(URI baseUrl, @RequestHeader("Authorization") String token);
}
```

ArticleClient that enriches the parameter manually:

```
@Service
public class ArticleClient extends AbstractFeignClientSupport {
    private final ArticleFeignClient articleFeignClient;

    @Autowired
    public ArticleClient(ArticleFeignClient articleFeignClient, AccessDataService accessDataService) {
        super(accessDataService);
        this.articleFeignClient = articleFeignClient;
    }

    public ArticleResponse getArticles(String connection, Integer id) {
        var accessData = getAccessDataByConnection(connection);
        return articleFeignClient.getArticles(URI.create(accessData.getEndpoint()), "Basic " + getAuthToken(accessData),id);
    }

    public MultiArticleResponse getArticles(String connection) {
        var accessData = getAccessDataByConnection(connection);
        return articleFeignClient.getArticles(URI.create(accessData.getEndpoint()), "Basic " + getAuthToken(accessData));
    }
}
```

Client support that holds the enricher

```
public abstract class AbstractFeignClientSupport {
    private final AccessDataService accessDataService;

    public AbstractFeignClientSupport(AccessDataService accessDataService) {
        this.accessDataService = accessDataService;
    }

    final public AccessData getAccessDataByConnection(@NotNull String connection) {
        return accessDataService.findOneByConnection(connection).orElseThrow();
    }
}
```

As you can see there will be many repetitions of

```
var accessData = getAccessDataByConnection(connection);
return clientToCall.methodToCall(URI.create(accessData.getEndpoint()), "Basic " + getAuthToken(accessData),id);
```

That simply adds the request's URI and Auth Header to the method call for the actual feign client.

I'm wondering if there's a better way and have been looking into using AOP or annotations that would intercept my method call, add the two parameters for every call in a given package (or annotated method), so that I'll only have to worry about it once and don't need to repeat that for 40 or so methods.

Is there? If so, how?

Comment: Yes, AOP would work; create an "Around" advice that adjusts the methods' parameters. I'd say it's a bit too involved to give a proper introduction into what's needed here. You need to first decide which methods to advise and how to determine them (eq mark with an annotation), then create an advice that implements the logic you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aspects tend to be a pretty dirty business, typesafety-wise.

To manipulate, say, a `List` passed to a method, you first need to extract it from the meta-information provided by the join point. This looks a bit like this:

```
@Pointcut("within(@com.your.company.SomeAnnotationType *)")
public void methodsYouWantToAdvise() {};

@Aspect
public class AddToList {
@Around("methodsYouWantToAdvise()")
public Object addToList(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
    Object[] args = thisJoinPoint.getArgs();
    // you know the first parameter is the list you want to adjust
    List l = (List) args[0];
    l.add("new Value");

    thisJoinPoint.proceed(args);
}
```

This can definitely be done better, but it's pretty much the gist of how you can implement such an aspect.

Maybe [check out this article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-aop-advice-tutorial) to get at least the foundations going.

Comment: IMO the problem rather is that many people don't know enough about aspects, not that the latter had any type-safety issues. If you use `args()` to bind the method parameter instead of using `JoinPoint.getArgs()`, it is perfectly type-safe and there are no ugly casts.

Comment: @kriegaex Interesting. What's `args()` declared on though, I can't find it.

Comment: I have added an extensive answer answering your question at first and in the end closing the loop back to the OP's original question.

Answer (score 1):

Because user [daniu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2837741/daniu) asked how to use `args()`, here is an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) using AspectJ (not Spring AOP, but the same pointcut syntax would work there):

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@SomeAnnotationType
public class Application {
  public void doSomething() {}
  public void doSomething(List<String> names) {}
  public void doSomethingDifferent(List<String> names) {}
  public void doSomethingInteresting(String... names) {}
  public void doSomethingElse(List<Integer> numbers) {}
  public void doSomethingGeneric(List objects) {}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    names.add("Albert Einstein");
    names.add("Werner Heisenberg");
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    numbers.add(11);
    numbers.add(22);

    Application application = new Application();
    application.doSomething();
    application.doSomething(names);
    application.doSomethingDifferent(names);
    application.doSomethingInteresting("Niels Bohr", "Enrico Fermi");
    application.doSomethingElse(numbers);
    application.doSomethingGeneric(names);
    application.doSomethingGeneric(numbers);

    System.out.println();
    for (String name : names)
      System.out.println(name);

    System.out.println();
    for (Integer number : numbers)
      System.out.println(number);
  }
}
```

Without any aspects applied, the console log is like this:

```
Albert Einstein
Werner Heisenberg

11
22
```

Now we add an aspect similar to daniu's, just using `args()` in order to bind a `List<String>` argument to an aspect pointcut parameter:

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import java.util.List;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public class AddToList {
  @Pointcut("@within(de.scrum_master.app.SomeAnnotationType) && execution(* *(..)) && args(names)")
  public void methodsYouWantToAdvise(List<String> names) {}

  @Around("methodsYouWantToAdvise(names)")
  public Object addToList(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint, List<String> names) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
    names.add(thisJoinPoint.getSignature().getName());
    return thisJoinPoint.proceed();
  }
}
```

Please note:

- Instead of `within(@de.scrum_master.app.SomeAnnotationType *)` as suggested by daniu I am using the more specialised `@within(de.scrum_master.app.SomeAnnotationType)`.
- I am adding `&& execution(* *(..))` because in AspectJ there are more than just `execution()` joinpoints, e.g. `call()` and I do not want to match the pointcut twice per method call + execution. In Spring AOP you can omit `&& execution(* *(..))` if you like.
- The `args(names)` pointcut designator only matches methods with a single `List` parameter, not methods with additional parameters. If you want to all match methods where the first parameter is a `List` but other parameters might follow, just use `args(names, ..)`.
- When compiling this aspect with the AspectJ compiler, you will see a warning: `unchecked match of List<String> with List when argument is an instance of List at join point method-execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomethingGeneric(List)) [Xlint:uncheckedArgument]`. What this means we will see in a minute.

Now let's look at the console log:

```
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomething(List))
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomethingDifferent(List))
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomethingGeneric(List))
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomethingGeneric(List))

Albert Einstein
Werner Heisenberg
doSomething
doSomethingDifferent
doSomethingGeneric

11
22
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer (java.lang.String and java.lang.Integer are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(Application.java:37)
```

As you can see, the pointcut only matches methods with a single `List<String>` parameter and excludes e.g. `doSomethingElse(List<Integer>)`, **but** it also matches `doSomethingGeneric(List)`, i.e. a method with a raw generic type. It even matches it twice, both when called with a `List<String>` parameter and a `List<Integer>` parameter.

Now this is not mainly an AspectJ problem but a Java generics limitation called type erasure. You can google that one if you like, it would be off-topic to explain it here in detail. Anyway, generally it means that during runtime you can add anything to the generic list, the JVM does not know that you might be adding a string to a list of integers, which is exactly what the aspect does in that case. Thus, when later in the for-loop we assume that all list elements are integers, we get the exception you can see on the console log above.

Now let's just change the last for-loop into this:

```java
for (Object number : numbers)
  System.out.println(number);
```

Then the exception goes away and the for-loop prints:

```
11
22
doSomethingGeneric
```

---

Now as for the original question, we don't have any problems with generics there, it is much easier. The pointcut would just look something like

```java
@Pointcut("@within(org.springframework.stereotype.Service) && execution(* *(..)) && args(connection, ..)")
public void methodsYouWantToAdvise(String connection) {}
```

This should match both `getArticles(..)` methods in the example above, but what then? Please note that the code you want to factor out is not completely identical. One time you have an ID and one time you don't. So either you make two pointcuts + corresponding advices (you can also inline the pointcuts, no need to specify them separately if you don't reuse them) or you do some ugly if-else stuff and again get the second, optional parameter via `getArgs()`. I think you should use two advices because you also call two different overloaded Feign client methods with different signatures (i.e. different parameter lists and different return types).

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use AOP to achieve this.  Feign has support `RequestInterceptors` that can be applied **before** a request is sent.

Here is an example from the [OpenFeign documentation](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign#request-interceptors)

```java
static class ForwardedForInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {
  @Override public void apply(RequestTemplate template) {
     template.header("X-Forwarded-For", "origin.host.com");
  }
}

public class Example {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  Bank bank = Feign.builder()
             .decoder(accountDecoder)
             .requestInterceptor(new ForwardedForInterceptor())
             .target(Bank.class, "https://api.examplebank.com");
  }
}
```

In this example, the `ForwardedForInteceptor` adds the header to every request that is sent using the `Bank` instance.

In your example, you could create an interceptor that relies on your enricher component to add additional parameters.

```java
 @Component
 public class EnrichInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {

    public AccessDataService accessDataService;

    public EnrichInterceptor(AccessDataService accessDataService) {
        this.accessDataService = accessDataService;
    }

    public void apply(RequestTemplate template) {
        AccessData data = this.accessDataService.getAccessByConnection(template.url());
        template.header("Authorization: Basic " + getToken(data));
    }
}
```

This example shows one way to modify a header using an interceptor.